# VBA code in Excel with pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

The data source will change often. After I refresh the pivot table, I have the following code to update the grade pivot item field. Sometimes grade 4 is available and sometimes it is not. Essentially, If grade 4 is available I want it to be selected and if it is not available then all fields can be select. For some reason when I run it, it stops on the else line. Any suggestions?

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Grade").ClearAllFilters

If IsError(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Grade").CurrentPage = "4") Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Grade").CurrentPage = _
    "(All)"    
Else  
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Grade").CurrentPage = "4"           
End If
```

Comment: have you tried the code in my answer below ? any feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't trap the `PivotField("Grade").CurrentPage` error with `IsError`.

Try the code below:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Grade").ClearAllFilters

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Grade").CurrentPage = "4"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Grade").CurrentPage = _
    "(All)"
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
```

**Note**: you could clean up your code if you use `With` statements. In your code, you could use `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Grade")`

Comment: It worked all a charm! Thank you so much for your help and your suggestion about using with.

Comment: @user7303815 your'e welcome, please mark as "Answer" (by clicking the little **V** next to my post)